# OpenCV 2.4.10 - Lipo can't open input file after upgrading to Xcode 6

Tags: opencv, frameworks, xcode6

I have been using Universal Frameworks for over a year now with no issues.  I have created new Universal Frameworks using Xcode 6 and the latest instructions.  All appears to work just fine until I try to add opencv2.framework to Link Binary With Libraries.  My guess is that I need an updated version of opencv2.framework that was built with Xcode 6.  But I'm not sure and hoping that someone else might have the answer.

Here is the output:

[image]

If you can't read that, here is the text:

```
2014-10-28 14:38:22.596 xcodebuild[43259:507] [MT] IDELogStore: Log record's backing file ("/Users/pdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestOpenCV-boyqihvbbxvpprbeguuarmklthxp/Logs/Build/EF8990BD-5170-4C90-972A-C7FD4B916AAA.xcactivitylog") is missing. Skipping.
2014-10-28 14:38:22.597 xcodebuild[43259:507] [MT] IDELogStore: Log record's backing file ("/Users/pdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestOpenCV-boyqihvbbxvpprbeguuarmklthxp/Logs/Build/0C1D3D3B-1490-4BE1-B908-51C74B145890.xcactivitylog") is missing. Skipping.
2014-10-28 14:38:22.597 xcodebuild[43259:507] [MT] IDELogStore: Log record's backing file ("/Users/pdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestOpenCV-boyqihvbbxvpprbeguuarmklthxp/Logs/Build/8E31CC46-E5B7-4EA0-9EC8-F312BBBFC30E.xcactivitylog") is missing. Skipping.
2014-10-28 14:38:22.597 xcodebuild[43259:507] [MT] IDELogStore: Log record's backing file ("/Users/pdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestOpenCV-boyqihvbbxvpprbeguuarmklthxp/Logs/Build/E82D620E-F41E-4A80-9583-135041DEF9CC.xcactivitylog") is missing. Skipping.
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/pdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestOpenCV-boyqihvbbxvpprbeguuarmklthxp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestOpenCV.framework/TestOpenCV normal i386
(1 failure)

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/pdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestOpenCV-boyqihvbbxvpprbeguuarmklthxp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TestOpenCV.framework/TestOpenCV normal armv7
(1 failure)

fatal error: lipo: can't open input file: /Users/pdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestOpenCV-boyqihvbbxvpprbeguuarmklthxp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestOpenCV.framework/TestOpenCV (No such file or directory)
Command /bin/sh emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
```

---

ADDED:

---

I have yet to figure out how to include opencv into my project **BUT** the reason that lipo can't open input file is because its not getting generated during the build.

I'm having so many problems with the build script for Xcode6.  Still trying to figure out if there is a problem with the script, environment variables, configuration, etc.

If anybody is reading this and they know how to create a Universal Framework (Fat Static Library) in Xcode6 please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27284192/1735836).

Thank you.

Comment: @ChrisMaes - I've moved the information from and answer to part of the question.  So you can permanently delete the answer.  FYI: The reason I had it as an answer is because the question was old and nobody was responding.