# Xcode6 Creating Fat Static Library iOS Universal Framework

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, xcode6, static-libraries

Since the upgrade to Xcode and iOS8, I've been having trouble building a fat static library.  There are some pretty good instructions [**here**](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework#mk-8-is-now-out-of-beta) and [**here**](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/12/13/building-a-universal-framework-for-ios/) but I think parts of the first instructions and all of the second instructions are dated.  The first instructions say to use **Static iOS Framework** and the second instructions say to use **Cocoa Touch Static Library**.  Prior to Xcode6, I would use the **Static iOS Framework** but now that they have renamed it to **Cocoa Touch Framework** I'm not sure.

So, for starters, which should I use to create a **fat static library**?  Is it **Cocoa Touch Framework**?  Or **Cocoa Touch Static Library**?

[image: Cocoa Touch Framework]

[image: Cocoa Touch Static Library]

Then I create a new Aggregate Target:

[image: Aggregate Target]

Then I create a Run Script:

---

[image: Run Script]

---

Here is the Run Script I am using (in its entirety):

```
# This script is based on Jacob Van Order's answer on apple dev forums 

https://devforums.apple.com/message/971277
# See also http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/12/13/building-a-universal-framework-for-ios/ for the start


# To get this to work with a Xcode 6 Cocoa Touch Framework, create Framework
# Then create a new Aggregate Target. Throw this script into a Build Script Phrase on the Aggregate


######################
# Options
######################

REVEAL_ARCHIVE_IN_FINDER=true

FRAMEWORK_NAME="${PROJECT_NAME}"

SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal"

FRAMEWORK="${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"


######################
# Build Frameworks
######################

xcodebuild -project ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj -sdk iphonesimulator -target ${PROJECT_NAME} -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator | echo

xcodebuild -project ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj -sdk iphoneos -target ${PROJECT_NAME} -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos | echo

#xcodebuild -target ${PROJECT_NAME} ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" | echo

#xcodebuild -target ${PROJECT_NAME} ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" | echo


######################
# Create directory for universal
######################

rm -rf "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"

mkdir "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"

mkdir "${FRAMEWORK}"


######################
# Copy files Framework
######################

cp -r "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/." "${FRAMEWORK}"


######################
# Make fat universal binary
######################

lipo "${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" -create -output "${FRAMEWORK}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" | echo


######################
# On Release, copy the result to desktop folder
######################

if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release" ]; then
mkdir "${HOME}/Desktop/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}-${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal/"
cp -r "${FRAMEWORK}" "${HOME}/Desktop/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}-${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal/"
fi


######################
# If needed, open the Framework folder
######################

if [ ${REVEAL_ARCHIVE_IN_FINDER} = true ]; then
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release" ]; then
open "${HOME}/Desktop/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}-${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal/"
else
open "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}/"
fi
fi
```

But when I try to Build I receive this message:

```
fatal error: lipo: can't open input file: /Users/pdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/innerIDMobileLicense-blnxjfvoxnqfelftmzojgdwhvazk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/innerIDMobileLicense.framework/innerIDMobileLicense (No such file or directory)
```

That's correct, the file isn't there!  Notice in the first image below, there is a Unix Executable File **IdAirOpenCv**.  Then look at the second image and notice that **IdAirOpenCv** isn't there.

This is what I am used to seeing prior to upgrading:

[image: Old folder structure]

This is what I have now:

[image: New folder structure]

According to the script, the Unix Executable File **innerIDMobileLicense** should be located inside all three of the framework folders at the same level as the Headers and Modules folders.

Does anybody have a clue what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> fatal error: lipo: can't open input file:
>   /Users/pdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/innerIDMobileLicense-blnxjfvoxnqfelftmzojgdwhvazk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/innerIDMobileLicense.framework/innerIDMobileLicense
>   (No such file or directory)

This lipo error you got is most likely due to the containing  directory does not exists.

The script is created when xcode does not have a framework project.

Lipo basically links two binary build for different architecture together to build a fat one.

> So, for starters, which should I use to create a fat static library?
>   Is it Cocoa Touch Framework? Or Cocoa Touch Static Library?

Either one will work. Lipo can link the binary inside the framework and a simple static library

What I did is to create a static library project, and a framework project. Set the static library target to be either device or simulator (using sdk iphoneos or iphonesimulator. Add the Universal Framework script into the framework project to build the static library with the other sdk and put the fat binary to the framework. Also copy needed headers to the framework project. The framework do not need to compile anything.

Comment: guangyan wang!  I would love to give you the points for this question but I need a little more info, PLEASE.  :-)  Sorry for the delay but I had to work on Android for awhile, so I'm only just getting back on this.  I did as you suggested and created one of each.  But I don't understand the difference between the two.  Cocoa Touch Framework says it is a template that creates a framework that uses UIKit.  Cocoa Touch Static Library says it is a template that builds a static library that links against the Foundation framework.  Can you explain the difference please.  Thank you.

Comment: To be clear:  My project is a framework to be used by customers' applications.  However, my framework uses the OpenCV framework.  So, I am trying to build a fat static library framework that Links Binary With Libraries opencv2.framework.  I noticed that Cocoa Touch Framework produced a .framework whereas the Cocoa Touch Static Library produced a .a.  Ultimately what I want is a .framework file that includes everything in its folder structure.  With Xcode 5, the script used the .a products and ultimately produced the Release-iphoneuniversal product.  Does this help?

Comment: guangyan wang!  I found an explanation of the differences between frameworks here:  https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework#mk-8-is-now-out-of-beta.

Comment: @Lucy Hi. My understanding of a fat library is it contains binary for both x64 x32 for simulators and arm series for real device. A .a static library is for either architecture but not for both. Lipo can combine two static library together to be a "fat" one. In my case, I created a framework and a fat static library, put the fat library inside the framework along with some headers. I am not sure about how to include another framework though. You may be able to include the opencv2.framework inside your framework

Comment: Hi, guangyan wang:  Yes, I can include the opencv2.framework to my framework.  I am closer now to being able to build.  Actually, I am building but I'm not getting the output files copied into the iphoneuniversal product folder.  Do you have a script that works for you that you could share?

Comment: @Lucy I am not allowed to share mine but it is similar with this one https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework/blob/master/scripts/build_framework.sh