# Old path persists in Xcode framework build

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

The following script is part of an aggregate target build phase that is supposed to be used to combine simulator and device targets into one universal framework build. The build originated from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284192/xcode6-creating-fat-static-library-ios-universal-framework).

```
set -e 

FRAMEWORK_NAME="${PROJECT_NAME}"

SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal"

FRAMEWORK="${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"


######################
# Build Frameworks
######################
echo "PROJECT_NAME: ${PROJECT_NAME}"
echo "CONFIGURATION: ${CONFIGURATION}"
echo "BUILD_DIR: ${BUILD_DIR}"
echo "SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH: ${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}"
echo "DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH: ${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}"
echo "UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR: ${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"

xcodebuild -project ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj -sdk iphonesimulator -target ${PROJECT_NAME} -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator
```

Here is the first error I get when executing this script:

```
PROJECT_NAME: My-project_Framework
CONFIGURATION: Debug
BUILD_DIR: /Users/foouser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-project_Framework-fjaslxiqhnitqxdksjbcxyuugfpk/Build/Products
SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH: /Users/foouser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-project_Framework-fjaslxiqhnitqxdksjbcxyuugfpk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/My-project_Framework.framework
DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH: /Users/foouser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-project_Framework-fjaslxiqhnitqxdksjbcxyuugfpk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/My-project_Framework.framework
UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR: /Users/foouser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-project_Framework-fjaslxiqhnitqxdksjbcxyuugfpk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneuniversal
Build settings from command line:
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/foouser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-project_Framework-fjaslxiqhnitqxdksjbcxyuugfpk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator8.1

=== CLEAN TARGET My-project_Framework OF PROJECT My-project_Framework WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

Create product structure
/bin/mkdir -p /Users/foouser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-project_Framework-fjaslxiqhnitqxdksjbcxyuugfpk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/My-project_iOS.framework

Clean.Remove clean /Volumes/local\ my-project/my-project/ios/Framework/build/My-project_Framework.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/My-project_Framework.build
    builtin-rm -rf /Volumes/local\ my-project/my-project/ios/Framework/build/My-project_Framework.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/My-project_Framework.build

Clean.Remove clean /Users/foouser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-project_Framework-fjaslxiqhnitqxdksjbcxyuugfpk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/My-project_iOS.framework
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/foouser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-project_Framework-fjaslxiqhnitqxdksjbcxyuugfpk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/My-project_iOS.framework

** CLEAN SUCCEEDED **

=== BUILD TARGET My-project_Framework OF PROJECT My-project_Framework WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
error: Unable to create directory: /Volumes/local my-project/my-project/ios/Framework/build (Permission denied)
```

**Now here is the problem**

This mount point, `/Volumes/local my-project` (with a space) has been *replaced* with `/Volumes/localmy-project` (without a space). Yet Xcode still seems to have the old path somewhere.

Here's what I did to try rip it out of Xcode (version 6.1.1):

1. Added the `echo` calls to the script to show all the command line inputs to `xcodebuild`. As you can see this path doesn't come in from the command line call.
2. Cleaned all targets (Choose each target, Product->Clean).
3. Checked all the files included in this framework project - all of them have `location` set to `Relative to Project` in the inspector.
4. Restarted Xcode.
5. Restarted the Mac.
6. Checked `project.pbxproj` and all other XML files found in the project package contents - no absolute path to be found.
7. Checked the target in the inspector - its location is absolute (cannot be changed) and correctly points to the new path (`/Volumes/localmy-project/...`)
8. Went into the organizer and went Projects->My-Project->Derived Data->Delete.

After all this, the error still persists. So - where is Xcode getting this old path from?

**Update**

I've added the following `echos` to show a few more build environment variables according to @Louis Tur:

```
BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR: /Users/foouser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-Project_Framework-fjaslxiqhnitqxdksjbcxyuugfpk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
CACHE_ROOT: /var/folders/w1/v31fpgnd7sl0yp5ctqjgsxsh0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.1.1-6A2008a/Xcode
CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR: /Users/foouser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-Project_Framework-fjaslxiqhnitqxdksjbcxyuugfpk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR: /Users/foouser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-Project_Framework-fjaslxiqhnitqxdksjbcxyuugfpk/Build/Intermediates/My-Project_Framework.build/Debug-iphoneos
SYMROOT: /Users/foouser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-Project_Framework-fjaslxiqhnitqxdksjbcxyuugfpk/Build/Products
```

**Update2 - Now with even more echos!**

```
DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION: NO
DERIVED_FILE_DIR: /Users/foouser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-project_Framework-fjaslxiqhnitqxdksjbcxyuugfpk/Build/Intermediates/My-project_Framework.build/Debug-iphoneos/My-project_Framework_Universal.build/DerivedSources
DSTROOT: /tmp/My-project_Framework.dst
INSTALL_DIR: /tmp/My-project_Framework.dst
INSTALL_PATH: 
OBJECT_FILE_DIR: /Users/foouser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-project_Framework-fjaslxiqhnitqxdksjbcxyuugfpk/Build/Intermediates/My-project_Framework.build/Debug-iphoneos/My-project_Framework_Universal.build/Objects
OBJECT_FILE_DIR_normal: /Users/foouser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-project_Framework-fjaslxiqhnitqxdksjbcxyuugfpk/Build/Intermediates/My-project_Framework.build/Debug-iphoneos/My-project_Framework_Universal.build/Objects-normal
OBJECT_FILE_DIR_debug: 
OBJROOT: /Users/foouser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-project_Framework-fjaslxiqhnitqxdksjbcxyuugfpk/Build/Intermediates
PROJECT_TEMP_DIR: /Users/foouser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-project_Framework-fjaslxiqhnitqxdksjbcxyuugfpk/Build/Intermediates/My-project_Framework.build
REZ_COLLECTOR_DIR: /Users/foouser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-project_Framework-fjaslxiqhnitqxdksjbcxyuugfpk/Build/Intermediates/My-project_Framework.build/Debug-iphoneos/My-project_Framework_Universal.build/ResourceManagerResources
REZ_OBJECTS_DIR: /Users/foouser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-project_Framework-fjaslxiqhnitqxdksjbcxyuugfpk/Build/Intermediates/My-project_Framework.build/Debug-iphoneos/My-project_Framework_Universal.build/ResourceManagerResources/Objects
SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR: /Users/foouser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-project_Framework-fjaslxiqhnitqxdksjbcxyuugfpk/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders
SRCROOT: /Volumes/localmy-project/my-project/ios/Framework
TARGET_BUILD_DIR: /Users/foouser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-project_Framework-fjaslxiqhnitqxdksjbcxyuugfpk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
TARGET_TEMP_DIR: /Users/foouser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-project_Framework-fjaslxiqhnitqxdksjbcxyuugfpk/Build/Intermediates/My-project_Framework.build/Debug-iphoneos/My-project_Framework_Universal.build
```

Still none of these point to the old path then..

Comment: cleared all your derived data for the project? Haven't experienced this myself, but you've piqued my curiosity. the `xcodebuild` man page mentions that build/clean references the build root, SYMROOT. And the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW42) on the matter makes me want to say to try to give a value to `BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR` and re-run the command

Comment: ah, or: `clean: Remove the product and build files in the product build directory (CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR) and the intermediate build files directory (CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR).` set those enviroment values

Comment: Thank you for your help. What do you mean by "cleared all your derived data"?

Comment: I've added a few more echos to check for the locations in your linked documentation (see edit). Still nothing.

Comment: Derived data: I understand now - deleted it in the organizer. I've also cleaned all targets again. Still nothing.

Comment: I'm outputting now every variable listed under `Build and Product Location Build Settings` in your link. `SRCROOT` is the only one that even points to the new mountpoint - nothing I can find points to the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know how that old path is coming in, but I've found a workaround that works for me: I can force the correct DerivedData path by using `xcodebuild` the following way (which replaces the old calls in the script):

```
xcodebuild -scheme ${PROJECT_NAME} -derivedDataPath ${BUILD_DIR}/../../ -project ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator

xcodebuild -scheme ${PROJECT_NAME} -derivedDataPath ${BUILD_DIR}/../../ -project ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj -sdk iphoneos -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos
```

If anyone has an idea where the old path could still persist, please let me know.

Comment: How can we force the correct DerivedData path by using xctool for oclint check.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem and solved by reset the Location  of Derived data folder in Xcode preference.
After setting, I quit Xcode and relaunch again. It solved.