# IOS Framework from C library give linking issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, frameworks, xcode6

I'am finalising an Open Source C coded CometD library, i thought it would be a good idea to open it to OSX/iOS users, like myself.

In order to ease up the work for OSX/iOS developers i wanted to switch from a static C library to a Xcode iOS Framework.
So i followed advices found on the net, and generated a static iOS compatible library from Xcode before wrapping it in a iOS FrameWork.

I made sure that "Architectures" is "Standard armv7 armv64" and 
the "Base SDK" is put to "Latest iOS" then i compiled, some warnings popped out but library generated successfully and gave me a Product.a .

The problem is that i can't include it in any other iOS project. 
As soon as i put the library and the headers in any iOS project i found a sea of error telling me :

ignoring file * * *.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): * * *.a
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

...

- barely all c functions

...

But it has compiled as a compatible iOS static library ? Why yelling at me for a i386 architecture ? Mind Blowing !

I fetched the interweb but no real answer was found.

So my question is, is it possible to make such a thing (C library inside iOS FrameWork) ? If yes (hopefully), how to avoid the errors and make it actually compile and produce a product ?

Any Answer would be much appreciated, Thank you for reading.

Comment: Hi. Do you understand why got this error? You should build universal framework (standart arch + i386 arch for simulator). E.g. read this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284192/xcode6-creating-fat-static-library-ios-universal-framework).

Comment: Hi :), no honestly i don't understand why, i got the idea that IOS development can have different arm architectures, but if i ask for a iOS library shouldn't it work with a iOS Framework ? I know that the answer is no and it is more complicated than that, but i find it really frustrating to get stuck in such configuration step at the end of a long project. I read the link you gave me, thank you. Following the link lead me to get rid of the i386 error and made my Framework exportable on projects but now i get a x86_64 missing symbols error. Even if Xcode show me the Func in autocompletion.

Comment: Do you get this error when building the app for device, e.g. iphone ?

Comment: Yes exactly, when i build for a defined device like Iphone 6... i get the x86_64 error. i can provide you my project or the code to see if its too blurry.

Comment: Ok. Post the link to your project.

Comment: Here is the link to how i made the static library from all my C code :
https://github.com/GhostGumm/C_To_iOS_framework
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Here is the link to how i tried to make a iOS Framework from the library : 
https://github.com/GhostGumm/iOS_FrameWork_From_C_Library

Thank you very much for dropping an eye on it.